# C# .net Core Fluentvalidation manual validation get validator class instance

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am trying to get the validator class instance instead of manually initiating in my method.

I am using Asp .net core webapi 2 where I register my validator in startup class using

```
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation().
```

In one of my action method, I had to validate a ruleset. So I am creating my validator class locally like

```
var validator = new MyClassValidator()
var result = validator.Validate(obj,ruleSet: "RulesetName");
```

I am trying to avoid this statement `var validator = new MyClassValidator()`. 
I would like to use IOC and get an instance. Any help?

Comment: Did you try to simply add the corresponding `IValidator<MyClass>` to the controller constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is required to register `MyClassValidator` in IoC container manually:

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<T>, MyClassValidator>();
```

[As documentation states](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-ASP.NET-Core-integration), you don't need to use an instance of this class manually, `FluentValidation` will validate it automatically.

> FluentValidation can be integrated with Asp.NET Core. Once enabled,
>   MVC will use **FluentValidation to validate objects that are passed in
>   to controller actions by the model binding** infrastructure.

Anyway, if you need to use this class manually, you can simply add a parameter of type `IValidator<T>` to your desired constructor.

Comment: Currently I am registering  services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<startup>()); Is it ok to add services.AddTransient<IValidator<T>, MyClassValidator>(); again? I feel we are registering the validator class twice..

Comment: `fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<startup>()` if you are calling this, your validator is already registered in IoC, so you can get in your constructor parameter.

Comment: yes using IValidator<MyClass> in constructor worked. I tried the same thing before creating this question but it didn't work that time.. Not sure what I missed.